# What is "redirects" in the Spotify JSON lookup API?

Tags: json, rest, spotify, asp.net-web-api

I'm working with the [Spotify public lookup API](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/lookup/) and I just stumbled into something weird.

A JSON lookup for [track 4y47sHvLLLX542a4NrBZqR](http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/.json?uri=spotify%3atrack:4y47sHvLLLX542a4NrBZqR) returns the following (amended for conciseness):

```
{
  track: {
    redirects: [
      "spotify:track:4y47sHvLLLX542a4NrBZqR"
    ],
    href: "spotify:track:496AcgphC6MqkWas0suAfN",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Now, two things look weird in this response:

1. The returned `href` does not match the ID used for the lookup (`496AcgphC6MqkWas0suAfN` vs. `4y47sHvLLLX542a4NrBZqR`)
2. There's an additional `redirects` array which I've never seen before

Another lookup for [the track referenced in `href`](http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/.json?uri=spotify%3atrack:496AcgphC6MqkWas0suAfN) returns the same exact JSON, but without `redirects`.

Does anyone know what this means? I assume there was some ID re-assignment in the history of that track and both versions were maintained for backwards compatibility, but I'd love to hear from someone with a more solid understanding of the API.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume there was some ID re-assignment in the history of that track and both versions were maintained for backwards compatibility.

Correct enough. Tracks can be redirected to other tracks for various reasons, the most common being when a track is unplayable in a user's locale but a functionally identical track is available. Seeing redirects like this in a context-less environment (i.e., one without a logged-in user) like the lookup API is rare, but as you've seen it can happen.

Comment: Thanks. What I still don't get is what's the original and what's the redirect.
I guess I'm confused by the fact that `redirects` lists the same ID I was looking for, but then the `href` is different.
In other words, isn't `href` enough to tell me there was a redirect? What is `redirects` for?

Comment: The json version of the API was not designed at all. It was just released as the internal representation made for the xml version, but directly serialized from python dict to json, because we didn't have time to implement it properly back then. That is why it looks a bit odd. As you said, having a different href is enough. The redirects that you found is not really supposed to be in the API.